# Is there a better phrase that means "non-zero–sum game?"

Tags: idioms

A "zero-sum game" is a reasonably well understood phrase, though often incorrectly used as "zero sum gain." The opposite of this is a "non-zero–sum game," which I find rather unwieldy. Is there a better phase than "non-zero–sum game?"

Comment: You used the dash in the wrong place: what you have written is a (non-zero)–sum game, which makes no sense.  When you start with a hyphenated word, like *zero-sum*, than to make another hyphenated compound, this time you use an en dash, making it a *non–zero-sum game*.  I might be tempted to create an open compound, but *non* doesn’t stand alone.

Comment: @tchrist - copied and pasted from the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero%E2%80%93sum_game). The logic applied was (presumably) that the game's collective value (sum) does not balance, thus is non-zero.

Comment: Yes there is a better phrase, namely a game where there are winners and losers.

Comment: @Chris - The point of a zero-sum game is that the winner's gains are _exactly_ offset by the loser's losses. If a pizza has 8 slices and you eat one, then someone else losses it. In a fixed budget, if you want to spend $50 on something then you have $50 less to spend on other things.

Comment: To chime in quite a bit too late, I think *non–zero-sum game* is better than *non-zero–sum game*. If you say  *(non-zero)–sum game*, you're implying that there is a sum, and that it's not zero. Thus, we get the incorrect answer *positive-sum* and *negative-sum.* However, the characteristic property of games that are not zero-sum is that the sum varies depending on what the players do. So it could be positive, negative, or zero, depending on the players' strategies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to **zero sum games**, there are also **positive sum games** and **negative sum games**. See this [discussion](http://www.beyondintractability.org/essay/sum).

> **Positive-sum** outcomes are those in which the sum of winnings and losses is greater than zero.
>
> **Negative-sum** situations [are those] where the pie is shrinking. In the end, the gains and losses will all add up to less than zero.

Apparently, these are related, but different from [*win-win games*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win-win_game).

> Though similar, these terms differ from the terms "win-win, win-lose, and lose-lose" which refer to wins or losses relative to expectations.

Comment: I think not.  In game theory there are games where the overall outcomes have a constant sum no matter what the choices of the participants and games which have a variable sum.  The former are called zero-sum games as the positive or negative constant should not affect optimal play (even if it sometime does affect real-life behaviour for psychological reasons).  The latter are called non-zero-sum games.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't be too sure a [zero sum game](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/zero-sum-game.html#ixzz26sTVHMQ7) is that well-known...

> In decision theory, situation where one or more participants' gain (loss) equals the loss (gain) of other participants. Thus, a gain (loss) for one must result in a loss (gain) for one or more others. Also called *constant sum game*. See also *negative sum game* and *positive sum game*.

But putting aside the more "academic" overtones of the above definition, I suppose when it's used in common parlance the focus is on the fact that there's no collective gain. So the *opposite* is a...

[Win-win game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win-win_situation) *(or more often, [Win-win negotiation](http://www.negotiations.com/definition/win-win/))*

Comment: @tchrist: I never typed a single one - all cut and pasted from the links. They're by no means *always* hyphenated. The popup won't hurt you, and it'll go away forever once you close it. Unlike links to the M-W and OED which are much worse.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The context that I most hear it is not gaming theory, rather allocating a fixed number of resources. For example: balancing a budget.

Comment: @dave: Perhaps I didn't express myself well, but that's what I meant by my last paragraph. For example, when you're trying to sort out the corporate budget, every gain for one department must be balanced by a loss for another. No matter what you do, there's no overall gain or loss - you're just shuffling the same fixed amount of money around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a gamer, so game theory is all new to me.  Clearly positive-sum and negative-sum are not what you are looking for either.  I came here seeking that apparently illusive opposite as well.

In my context the win/win vs. win/lose concept are close but too vague for my liking.  After reading this thread I have chosen to coin (or unconsciously plagiarize) the phrase "Infinite-Sum game.

Answer (score 0):

virtuous circle or virtuous cycle 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuous_circle_and_vicious_circle
context of abundance rather than shortage - authentic collaboration rather than extractive 'teamwork'