# Looking for the inverse -- not the opposite -- of "zero-sum game"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I have 5 dollars, and I exchange them for your banana, that's a zero-sum game.

If I have a candle, and I use it to light yours, that is not a zero-sum game. It could be said to be the opposite of a zero-sum game, and I'd like to know if there's a more apt description.

Now, what if there's some really infectious disease? Eradicating it in one case curbs the macro-epidemic, and spreading it to another is likely to cause an exponential rise.

This seems to me the inverse of a zero-sum game. How is it this concept best generically referred to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better phrase that means "non-zero–sum game?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83050/is-there-a-better-phrase-that-means-non-zerosum-game)

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: In fact, I definitely can't tell which of those terms maps to which of my examples.

Comment: Fair call - as long as you've seen it.

Comment: When you combine two things and the result is more than the mere arithmetical sum of the two the operation is said to possess 'synergy'. I don't know if that helps. What the inverse amounts to I have no idea.

Comment: A zero-sum game means that whatever one party gains the other loses. Here the two sides are gaining/losing different things. A banana is not $5. They are different. So it's not a zero-sum game. Ideally both sides would gain in such a transaction according to their economic utility functions.

Comment: Any potential difference in value is purely subjective, though, is it not?

Comment: A zero sum game (poker, for example) is, first and foremost, a game.  Neither your candle example or the infectious disease example sound much like games.  Hence, you may wish to rethink the idea that you're looking for a game.

Comment: Well, I'm not attempting to refer to a game. I'm attempting to refer to something else as a game metaphorically. This is literary prose, not technical writing on game theory.

Comment: @user3025492: What you used in your examples (flame, epidemic) are both non-zero sum game. In case of the candle, it's a positive-sum game; in case of the epidemic, it's a negative-sum game.

Comment: How can you differentiate between a positive sum game which increases sum through proactive action and one which some small proactive action set the stage and create a proneness for further increase without as heavy or any intervention in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Zero sum game" is originally an economic term, and so the phrase you're looking for might be an economic term.

Your candle example is an example of what economists call a non-[rivalrous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivalry_%28economics%29) resource. Basically that means that your consumption of a good does not prevent the simultaneous consumption by another. Other examples of non-rivalrous goods are information, clean air, or a scenic view. This is opposed to rivalrous goods like gold or gasoline.

The infectious disease example is more an example of a [positive externality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Externality). This is a more complicated concept. Wikipedia describes a positive externality as a benefit that affects a party that did not choose (or pay for) that benefit. Another way of thinking about positive externalities is to say that a positive externality exists when an individual does not (and cannot) fully gain the full benefit of its decision. If an infected individual invests time or money to treat or prevent a disease, the individual *does* benefit, but the rest of society also benefits. It is impractical for the infected individual to charge everyone who benefits from his responsible medical decisions, and so he is unable to capture the full economic value of his decision. This is related to the free-rider problem, which points to the fact that if most people get vaccinated, the people who don't get vaccinated benefit from this without having to go through the cost or discomfort of getting vaccinated.

Externality and rivalry are related concepts, and often both exist at the same time. For example, if I plant a nice garden, my neighbors benefit from it for free in that they get a nicer view from their homes. That's a positive externality. At the same time, their enjoyment of the garden does not interfere with my enjoyment of the garden and vice-versa. Some aspects of the garden, then, are non-rivalrous goods.

So depending on which aspect of the "non-zero sum"ness you're looking at, you might be thinking about these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Your disease example reminds me of the term ***chain reaction***. From NOAD:

> **chain reaction** [*figurative*] a series of events, each caused by the previous one : *an article in one publication sets off a chain reaction in the media.*

Your candle example reminds me of the expression ***pay it forward***, an expression which isn't established enough to make it into dictionaries yet, but is enjoying [growing popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay%20it%20forward&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,pay%20it%20forward;,c0) thanks to the [film of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_It_Forward). The phrase actually goes back well before that book (*"You don't pay love back, you pay it forward,"* wrote Lily Hammond in 1913), and the concept even well before that, explains one author in forward to a work entitled *The Circle of a Good Deed: Pay It Forward from Concept to Philosophy to Practice*.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the term "non-zero-sum" is quite apt, I wonder why there was no mentioning of the term **positive-sum** (and also *negative-sum*, when the net effect is negative).

I found an example use of *positive-sum game* [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01237908).

> **The role of positive-sum games in economic growth**
>
> Abstract
>
> "Positive-sum games specific to dynamic equilibrium are contrasted to zero-sum games associated with static equilibrium. It is shown how the involved synergistic interactions and dynamic flexibilities explain how economic growth comes about."

So I believe you could use either *positive-sum* or *negative-sum*, depending on your case.

Answer (score -1):

Is this solely a mathematical question? I don't think so as we're on a language site. "Zero Sum Game" is often used to describe a way of seeing the world that is limited, linear and competitive. My concern with "Positive Sum" and "Negative Sum" Games as any kind of inverse or opposite is that they don't break the paradigm -- they are variations, and they still involve the limitation of a "sum." "Non-zero sum game" tells us very little; as a rule you don't use the negation of something as a definition. To counter "limited-linear-competitive," I came up with "infinite-divergent-cooperative," but these aren't able to win converts. The more credible "capacity-building/expansion/fluidity"concepts would mean that business models can incorporate growth without the heavy burden of having to "win over" assets from another business; their internal potential is not fixed, as 'capacity-building' is an accepted concept that strengthens and grows current resources and doesn't strain credulity like 'infinite' or force unnatural cooperation.'Fluidity' is the quality and mindset of change as a given, of the nimble reaction to the unexpected, without which *everything* seems like a ZSG. Expansion can make more room for everyone *(like the model of the balloon and the expanding universe)* or more typically uses aggression to make gains without concern for the impact on others. The Abundance/Scarcity duality captures the debate as well as anything. With that, I'd give the name "Expansion Paradigm Framework" to represent ZSG's inverse. Here's an apt analogy: You have a newborn child. In material terms, where did it come from? It didn't exist before and now here it is. (You can say it's a +1 in a Positive Sum Game, but that's too easy.) It's "capacity-building" as in strengthening, adding and growing from within. And when you consider that you probably love this child, where was this love before? From whose market share did you appropriate the quantity of love with which you now shower this child? The answer: You didn't *appropriate* anything, you *created* something: you expanded, and no one was crowded out by it. In fact, it's a value-added proposition. I turned the economic, mathematical, concept into a metaphor in the language realm; now can some creative economist flip this idea back to hard science and make it work in the board room?